# How to create a wrapper for `std::make_unique<T>`?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, std

I'd like to create a wrapper for `std::unique_ptr<T>` and `std::make_unique<T>` because I think they look ugly and take too long to type. (Yes, I'm that kind of person).

I have completed my `UniquePtr` type alias with no problem but cannot get my `MakeUnique` to work. It seems to be a bit of a rabbit hole, and was wondering if anyone here might be able to give me a hand with this?

What I have so far:

```
template <class T>
using UniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T>;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
UniquePtr<T> MakeUnique<T>(Args... args) // recursive variadic function
{
    return std::make_unique<T>(args);
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `cannot get my MakeUnique to work` - this is not a question. Please post [mcve]. Also, by stating that standard names are "ugly" you are actually lowering your chances of getting a good response.

Comment: `snake_case_is_the_best`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot just don't :)

Comment: you could write a macro /s

Comment: @SergeyA I am converted to the snake. I also east const, auto all variable (and explicitly putting type on the right side of the `=`) and trailing return type for every function. I am a lost soul.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot it is not about your style, it is about proselytizing it ;)

Comment: @pm100 run for cover?

Comment: @SergeyA the question is quite clear in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to forward properly the values, and you need to expand the pack.

First, make it compile:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
UniquePtr<T> MakeUnique(Args... args) // not recursive
{ //                   ^---- no need for <T> when defining function template 
    return std::make_unique<T>(args...); // the ... expands the pack
}
```

Then, you need to forward, because `args...` will copy everything. You want to move rvalues, and copy lvalues:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
UniquePtr<T> MakeUnique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```